# Item menu to module

Tags: php, module, joomla1.5, menuitem

How do I create a module that shows the same content displayed in a menu item in joomla 1.5?
I have a website in Joomla 1.5 with an employment component.
The component allows creating menu item to display jobs in a specific category.
I want to show this menu item in a module to show jobs by category.
The componete only has a module that combines all employment categories mixed in a single list.
How do I create a module that shows the same content displayed in a menu item?

Comment: why don't you make a copy of the menu module you want and put it wherever? [How to copy module (youtube)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykJcLiVpgP8)

Comment: I could use the mainmenu module and indicate to the menu you want. The problem is that the module mainmenu only shows content when clicking on item.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the {loadposition} plugin (comes with Joomla) to load the position into the module? Either that or look for a module that will allow you to load another module within it on extensions.joomla.org

Comment: I do not want to read a module, I want to become a menu item to a module.
I could use the mainmenu module and indicate to the menu you want. The problem is that the module mainmenu only shows content when clicking on item.